# Select All Checkbox not working in yii

Tags: php, ajax, checkbox, yii

I am New to Yii. In my project I had used checkbox for search. The search is working fine except in the case of "select all" option. The code I used is 
 `echo CHtml::activeCheckBoxList($category, 'category',
            CHtml::listData(Category::model()->findAll(), 'id', 'category'),                     array('checkAll' => '<strong>All Categories</strong>','separator'=>'','template'=>'<li><div class="checkbox"><label>{input} {label}</label></div></li>'));`

 and the Ajax code for search is 
 `$("input[type=checkbox]").click(function(){var categoryVals = [];
             categoryVals.push('');
            $('#Category_category :checked').each(function() {
              categoryVals.push($(this).val());
           //  alert("Checked");
            });
             var contryVals = [];
             contryVals.push('');
            $('#Country_name :checked').each(function() {
              contryVals.push($(this).val());
           //  alert("Checked");
            });                                                                       $.ajax({
                type:"POST", url:"<?php echo $this->createUrl('ads/searchresult'); ?>",
                data:{'category': categoryVals,'contry': contryVals},
                success : function(response){
                   $('.featured-listing-bottom').html(response);} 
                });});` 
 Here when selects the option "All Categories", its passing category value as 1(Not passing all categories id) and also when unchecking All categories it passing all the previously selected values.
 How can I solve this.
 Please some body help me..

Comment: handle server side.....

Comment: if you know all the categoris server side.. then you are passing 1 ... that all categories are selected... so check if that is 1 server side ... then use all categories...

Comment: Does I can change that value=1 for All categories.

Comment: on check of all categories ...  create javascript which will check all checkbox and ...submit the form....